# Test Angular Factory/Service Generated by Yeoman

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, yeoman

I have created an app with yeoman

```
yo angular --minsafe
```

And I want to test a factory/service I created

```
yo angular:factory analyticsService
```

Which produces /app/scripts/services/analyticsService.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularPlaygroundApp')
  .factory('analyticsService', function ($resource) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    var meaningOfLife = 42;

    // Public API here
    return {
      someMethod: function () {
        return meaningOfLife;
      }
    };
  });
```

and the test /test/spec/services/analyticsService.js

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: Analyticsservice', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('angularPlaygroundApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var Analyticsservice;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_Analyticsservice_) {
    Analyticsservice = _Analyticsservice_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!Analyticsservice).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

> running grunt test produces the following failed test for the service
>
> Running "karma:unit" (karma) task INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.8 server
>   `started at http://localhost:8080`/ INFO [launcher]: Starting browser
>   Chrome WARN [watcher]: Pattern
>   "/Users/lsims/projects/angular-playground/test/mock/**/*.js" does not
>   match any file. INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0)]: Connected
>   on socket MTgYIXPHDT3JCSNU0ww9 Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0)
>   Service: Analyticsservice should do something FAILED  Error:
>   [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AnalyticsserviceProvider <-
>   Analyticsservice

My question is how does one test factories/services in Angular, and more specifically, how can one test the services and/or factories that Yeoman generates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: EXACT same problem. This is my first experience with Yeoman, and it's been a good one, but little gotchas like this are eating up my nights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are tested pretty much exactly as you have described.  However, JavaScript is case sensitive, and you have changed the case of what the injector is going to search for.

> analyticsService != Analyticsservice

The `_Analyticsservice_` syntax allows you the wrap the literal value of your service in underscores so that you can then name the local variable to the same thing.  So, asking `inject` for `_Analyticsservice_` is asking for a service named with the string `"Analyticsservice"`.  When you have defined a service with the name `"analyticsService"`.

So, I think you want:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: analyticsService', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('angularPlaygroundApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var analyticsService;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_analyticsService_) {
    analyticsService = _analyticsService_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!analyticsService).toBe(true);
  });
```

`injector` in angular always appends the name `Provider` to the end of the objects in manages.  The the error is telling you that the injector could not find an object with the name `"AnalyticsserviceProvider"` defined.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Yeoman does a great job, but it (and I) missed the capitalization.  What is the convention for services, controllers, directives anyway?  It seems to vary based on example, e.g. MyCtrl vs myCtrl, MyService vs myService.

Comment: The only convention that angular enforces is naming in directives.  If you name a directive with camel case "myDirective", then you can refer to it in HTML in snake case "my-directive" or in camel case "myDirective" or (I think) with a colon "my:directive".  This allows the us to match different HTML standards.

Comment: @binarygiant: you can't possibly be blamed for missing the capitalization. the generator actually messes it up.